# hide div when another div is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this :

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#show").load("show.php");
}
```

and my html :

```
<div id='loader'>Loading Data</div>
<div id='show'></div>
<div id='other'>some text.........</div>
```

What I want is, on page loaded, html show `<div id='loader'>` and `<div id='other'>` when JS/JQuery success loaded the `<div id='show'>` then hide `<div id='loader'>`

Can you help me?

Comment: load method has an option to add complete callback method. do like this $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});   http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @techLove you're brilliant.. I modified your answer into this `$( "#show" ).load( "show.php", function() { 
     $("#loader").css("display","none"); 
    });`

Comment: @Michael ups, I didn't realized I chose the java tag instead of javascript. I really meant javascript and I know the difference of those. Thank you for edit it.

Comment: @Dika No problem. It's a common mistake. I've deleted my comments. Feel free to do the same with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @techLove's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893043/hide-div-when-another-div-is-loaded#comment74820114_43893043), I found this working on me. I modified his answer into this: 
 `$( "#show" ).load( "show.php", function() {$("#loader").css("display","none");});`

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` provide a `callback` you can use this. Just updated your js with following

```
$("#show").load("show.php", function(){
   $('#loader, #show').toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

load() has a callback that runs when it is complete. Use this to show and hide the relevant divs. You should also use jQuery ready function instead of window.onload so that the page won't have to wait for all resources (images etc) before it can load in the php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").load("show.php", function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
});
```

EDIT: Super User's answer provides a better solution than using .hide(), wish I'd thought of it!